# React npm start doesn't work after installing react-router-dom

Tags: reactjs, npm-start

I have installed a new package ('react-router-dom') and now my project doesn't start.
I get this warning:
[image: t work]

How can I resolve this problem?
Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

the current version (don't support webpack4) of this package does not work with `html-webpack-plugin v4`
Please refer this [issue](https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/preload-webpack-plugin/issues/79)

or

you can try yarn add `preload-webpack-plugin@3.0.0-beta.3`

**If the above method doesn't works:**

If you ejected from `create-react-app` and are getting this error upon `yarn build`, make sure the `InterpolateHtmlPlugin` line comes after the `HtmlWebpackPlugin` line in your webpack config file(s):

```
module.exports = {
  //...
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      // ...
    }),
    new InterpolateHtmlPlugin(env.raw),
    //..
  ]
}
```

Comment: It still doesn't work, I still get the same error message, thanks so much for trying to help

Comment: Can you share you webpack file?

Comment: `webpack.config.dev.js` this one?

Comment: check the post, i updated! Let me know if that works for you.

Comment: still not work. thanks for the help! I open a new project and move the old fils into it, it looks like it works now.